# Can I use the word spectrum to denote black, white and shades of grey in between?

Tags: single-word-requests

If a process has largely but not solely two outcomes but also has various intermediate outcomes interpolated between the first two main outcomes.  Then can I use the word spectrum?

I guess I could but I feel like that depicts a range of colours when actually a better comparison would be to say black, white and various shades of grey in between.

It feels odd to me to use the word spectrum for something that is *monochromatic*.  Am I being too strict with myself here?

Alternative words welcome.

Comment: Spectrum works, grayscale, too. If you say outcomes likely fall into the extremes, we know there are others in between.

Comment: What has the word spectrum got to with outcomes? A range of outcomes. three colors would give you three possible outcomes. A spectrum implies a band or position on a scale. Maybe yours is just black to white?

Comment: What did the definition of "spectrum" say when you looked it up? Is there some reason (not a feeling, but an actual reason) why you believe that the definition may be wrong? And finally, are you asking the question in the title, for a single word (as the tag suggests), or both?

Comment: @YosefBaskin & Lambie  _grayscale_ , _scale_ and  _range_ are all quite good. But I want now to hone in on how the two outcomes occupy 99.5% of the possibility space (split evenly in half) whilst the intermediate outcomes only occupy 0.5% of the possibility space.  It is like there is a black space and a white space and a "smudge" where the two meet.   (Sorry if this is turning into a riddle).

Comment: "Spectrum" is frequently used metaphorically.

Answer (score 1):

If all possible shades of grey are found between the black part and the white one, then you can use "the spectrum". If not all shades are found you can still use "spectrum", but you have to change  the article, which is "a" in the present case. This being so because "spectrum" is defined as follows.

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/spectrum?q=spectrum)) ​ 
> [usually singular] a complete or wide range of related qualities, ideas, etc.
> •  a broad spectrum of interests
> •  We shall hear views from across the political spectrum.

- *the* spectrum of greys between black and white (*all shades of grey*)
- *a*  spectrum of greys between black and white (*not all shades of grey*)

([ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Bulletin_international_de_l_Acad%C3%A9mie_po/67zRAAAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22a+spectrum+of%22&dq=%22a+spectrum+of%22&printsec=frontcover)) This duality can be explained by an assumption that the spectrum of chlorophyll of a leaf is not a spectrum of mixture of green pigments , but it is composed of two distinct spectra of neochloropbyll and allochlorophyll

([ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/The_perfect_way/RJCZEAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22the+spectrum+of%22&pg=PA280&printsec=frontcover))  … which, acting on the retina of the eye, constitute the spectrum of seven simple colours ;

Comment: I agree it's possible. Whether it's a good idea is more subtle. It could be pleasingly ironic, or confusing and irksome depending on presentation.